# Why is property initialization optional for non-optional properties in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

Consider this example:

```
class A {
    optional?: string;
    nonOptional: string;
    constructor() {

    }
}

let a = new A();

function consumeString(str: string) {
    console.log(str.length);
}

consumeString(a.optional);
consumeString(a.nonOptional);
```

With strictNullChecks enabled, TypeScript 2.4.2 will reject the first call;

> Argument of type `'string | undefined'` is not assignable to parameter of type `'string'`.
>     Type '`undefined' is not assignable to type`'string'`.

However, at runtime, the second call would fail as well, since `a.nonOptional` does not refer to a string.

Why does TypeScript not force initialization of `nonOptional`?

Comment: I've found [this discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476) on the TypeScript issue tracker.

Comment: That's a great link, you should write that up as a full answer!

Answer (score 2):

This was bug or misdesign in TypeScript that was fixed in TypeScript 2.7.

TypeScript 2.7 by default rejects your code and would say that `nonOptional` needs to be initialized.

TypeScript 2.7  introduced `strictPropertyInitialization` feature that requires that mandatory fields of classes must be initialized in contstructor (or my assigning defaults).

(You can disable this check passing `strictPropertyInitialization = false` to compiler to revert to TypeScript <2.7 behavior but that is not encouraged).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler won't tell you how to code.
You are free to assign a value at any given time, as long as it's a string, the compiler won't argue.  If you don't, that's valid as well.

If you want to safeguard against this then change the type to:

```
nonOptional: string | undefined;
```

Then this:

```
consumeString(a.nonOptional);
```

Will result in:

> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'string'.
>   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: @Aron who claims that ts is type safe?  it gives you the tools for it, but you can always make mistakes

Comment: isn't the whole point that it prevents you from making typing errors?

Comment: @Aron I don't think so, because you're not even forced to use the type system. For example, you also don't have to use `strictNullChecks`, and in that case the compiler won't complain about any parts of the code in this post.  Again, you get the tools, you choose how/when to use them

Comment: It helps you to avoid type errors, it doesn't prevent them.

Comment: Type safety and null checking are different things. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety for reference.

Comment: @Aron The point of TypeScript is to try and improve EMCAScript, and it takes a very pragmatic approach. One of the major ways it tries to help is by adding types and type safety wherever possible. But as part of being pragmatic it doesn't force such things where it would cause lots of issues with existing code. phant0m went to the TypeScript repository and found (this)[https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8476] issue. It's the language designers discussing this case: "Having looked at several code bases, I don't think it is feasible to implement this feature as we have discussed it."